# Error Screens for Different Internal Server Errors

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net

I have a custom error page setup to handle both error codes of 404 and 500 in a .NET application running with IIS:

**web.config**

```
  <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="/shared/error_pages/500.aspx">
      <error statusCode="404" redirect="/shared/error_pages/404.aspx"/>
      <error statusCode="500" redirect="/shared/error_pages/500.aspx"/>
  </customErrors>
```

**Global.asax**

```
Sub Application_Error(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

    Dim ex = Server.GetLastError()
    Dim sessionid = Trim(Request.Cookies("sessionid").Value)
    If (TypeOf ex Is HttpException) Then
        Dim httpex = CType(ex, HttpException)
        Dim httpCode = httpex.GetHttpCode()
        Dim innerEx = httpex.InnerException.Message
        If (httpCode <> 404) Then
            Dim _params As New NameValueCollection
            _params.Add("@edit", 1)
            _params.Add("@page_name", sender.Request.CurrentExecutionFilePath)
            _params.Add("@error_message", httpex.Message)
            _params.Add("@error_stacktrace", httpex.StackTrace)
            _params.Add("@sessionid", sessionid)
            TNXCDataAdapter.Execute("procedure", _params)
        End If
    End If

End Sub here
```

The above code I am just logging all non 404 errors to a datasource.  What I am trying to achieve here is pinpointing certain 500 errors, specifically, "Session is invalid" errors and have it hit another page besides the custom 500 error page defined in the web.config.  My knowledge of how the Global.asax file works is a little bit novice.  Since I am logging the error, if I could pass some data to the custom page that seems like one option.  Another being setting this up differently to define my custom pages inside the global.asax file.  Suggestions on the most efficient way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

**It's a Working Idea in my Project**

**Step 1.** You can generate a unique ID with [random id with alphanumeric and append with timestamp] in Application_error in global.asax page.
**Step 2.** After generating the Unique ID, use log4net and put that in a log text file.
**Step 3.** After that you pass the unique ID as query parameter to the redirect page in Application_error in global.asax page.
**Step 4.** Remove the 500 in customErrors  tag in web config file.
**Step 5 .** Finally in the custom error page read all lines in the log file , with the unique id you can get the error details from the log file. and show on the error page

**Note :** *the log4et creates a new file everyday, so you don't need to worry about the size of the log file.*

**Hope it works in yours requirement.**